# PHP Shopping cart, adding multiple items

Tags: php, cart

```
if (!empty($_GET['action'])) {
    $j = $_GET['id_'];
    switch($_GET['action']) {
        case "add":
        $query = "select * from ogl where id = $j";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
        $array = array($row["id"]=>array('seller'=>$row["seller"], 
        'name'=>$row["name"], 'cpu'=>$row["CPU"], 'size'=>$row["size"], 
        'price'=>$row["price"], 'img'=>$row["img"])); 

        if (empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $array;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"], $array);
        } 
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it adds only one item by replacing the previously added one. Each item has its ID which is sent by their button - GET method. What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- Read over this and then you can edit this question. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish and shouldn't have to figure that out in order to help you with your question. Give a little more background on your problem. I'll retract my down vote if you do ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are merging the contents of array into the existing array called "cart_item". However, any key of an array can only exist once. so by merging another shopping car item, you are overriding the one already there.

You could handle it like this:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
       // make sure the cart_item key exists before adding anything to it.
       $_SESSION['cart_item'] = array();
       $_SESSION["cart_item"][] = $array;
    } 
    else {
       $_SESSION["cart_item"][] =  $array;
    }
```

However, this means that you can add the same product twice. Since everything has their own ID, you could consider using $row['id] as the key for items.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you push an item into the array instead of replacing it ?

replace this line (and make the same for below code in the else)

```
$_SESSION["cart_item"] = $array;
```

by

```
$_SESSION["cart_item"][$j] = $array;
```

or better:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$j] = $array;
```

Make sure you define $_SESSION['cart'] somewhere near the start of the session

Answer (score 0):

make the cart stored in session be a string, with elements separated by a character like ';' and those elements could themselves be lists separated by a different character like ','.

The session/cookie would look like:

```
<id>,<seller>,<name>,<CPU>,<price>,<img>;
<id>,<seller>,<name>,<CPU>,<price>,<img>;
<id>,<seller>,<name>,<CPU>,<price>,<img>
```

This means that you could split the string with ";" and then every element in that array with ",".

To implement this you would switch this:

```
$_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"], $array);
```

for this:

```
$_SESSION["cart_item"] .= $row["seller"] . "," . $row["CPU"] . "," //and so on
```

Also, be carefull with sql_injection. You can change the "id_" parameter to a SQL query and damage you database.